# How to select specific numbers within an Array to Randomize? C++

Tags: c++, arrays, random, dice

I have a dice assignment to code, and basically there are 6 dices that we roll. Once it's rolled, all values (other than a single 1 or 5) can be rolled again .

The functions in order to randomize the whole Die has been finished, I'm only showing a small portion of the code which specifically asks for the user input on which dice to be re-rolled (For example, the 5th dice). And then, I select the 5th element of the dice and randomize the number again.

My intentions are to be able to create like this:

You have rolled:
5     3     6     4     2    1
[1]   [2]   [3]   [4]   [5]  [6]
Which dices do you want to re-roll? (1-6) //Input

//and then after choosing which dice to reroll, (for example dices, 2-5)

5     5     2     3     1     1
[1]   [2]   [3]   [4]   [5]   [6]

Your turn has ended, you gained 100 points from two 5s and 200 points from two 1s.

How do I create a code that can receive an input, which can then be used to select the nth element of an array to be randomized again? Thanks

```
    cout << "All dices you've rolled are scoring dices!\n";
        cout << "Do you wanto to [q]uit, [r]oll or [s]score";
        cin >> question; 

        if (question == 'q') {
            system("pause");
            exit();
        }
        else if (question == 'r') {
            cout << "Which dice(s) do you want to set aside? \n";
            cout << "(1-6) Enter which dice(s) without any spaces";
            cin >> choice;  
            for (int i : choice) {
               /* This is the place where I enter the code to be able to randomize the nth element of an array with another function */
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your question? How to assign to an array?  How to generate random numbers? How to convert a char containing the ASCII representation of a number to an actual number?

Comment: Do you need to keep the _positions_ of the dice? Because else you want `std::remove_if (... not 1 or 5 ...)`.

Comment: I think you're stuck on this because you're not quite finished with the first roll yet.